# Category of separated presheaves (over any site)

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory

It is well-known that the category of discrete fibrations over a category $\mathbb{C}$ is equivalent to the category of presheaves on $\mathbb{C}$.

More generally I think it is true, and probably well-known, though I can't find a reference, that the following two categories are equivalent:

1. the category with objects: discrete fibrations $\mathbb{E} \to \mathbb{B}$
   and morphisms: pairs of functors ($\mathbb{E}\to \mathbb{E}'$, $\mathbb{B} \to \mathbb{B}'$) making the square commute
2. the category with objects: pairs ($\mathbb{B}$, $P_\mathbb{B}: \mathbb{B}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$) consisting of a category and a presheaf on it, and morphisms: pairs $(f : \mathbb{B} \to \mathbb{B}', \alpha : P_\mathbb{B} \Rightarrow P_{\mathbb{B}'} \circ f^\mathrm{op})$ consisting of a functor and a natural transformation.

Suppose $\mathbb{B}$ is a site (i.e. has a topology), then the full subcategory of separated presheaves on $\mathbb{B}$ is a reflective subcategory of the category of all presheaves.

My question is: 
Consider the variation of (2) above where the objects are ($\mathbb{B}, P_\mathbb{B}$) where $\mathbb{B}$ is a site. Call this $\mathbf{C}$.
Is it true that the full subcategory of $\mathbf{C}$ whose objects are ($\mathbb{B}, P_\mathbb{B}$) with $P_\mathbb{B}$ separated is a reflective subcategory of $\mathbf{C}$?

Comment: Are you imposing any compatibility between the functors $f$ and the topologies of the sites?

Comment: I didn't think I'd need to, but I will if it makes the property true.

Comment: Well, *something* is needed.  Suppose $B$ and $B'$ are the same underlying category, with $f$ the identity functor, but $B'$ has the trivial topology (so all presheaves are sheaves) while $B$ does not.  If $P$ is a presheaf on this category $B=B'$ that's not separated for $B$, then the identity map $(B,P) \to (B',P)$ is a map to a separated object, but can't factor through any map from a separated object over $B$, while I think you should be able to show that any reflection of $(B,P)$ into a separated object of $\bf C$ must still be over $B$.

Comment: You could start with https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/morphism+of+sites.  I don't know whether this is the condition you need; there is also a dual notion of when a functor "reflects" covering families.